# make the text box required when i check the checkbox

Tags: jquery

I would like to make the text box mandatory when I check the checkbox, And disabled otherwise. I tried to use `.next()` and `.closest()` but I could not get it to work.

```
<div class="clearfix col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><label><input class="checkbox-inline input-lg" name="type[email]" type="checkbox"> E-mails</label></div>   
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input class="form-control" name="emquantity" max="999999999" type="number" ></div>                  
</div>
<div class="clearfix col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><label><input class="checkbox-inline input-lg" name="type[sms]" type="checkbox"> sms</label></div>   
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input class="form-control" name="smsquantity" max="999999999" type="number" ></div>                  
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer  after your modified question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be helpfull to you.

```
<div class="clearfix col-lg-6">
<div class="col-xs-8"><label><input class="checkbox-inline input-lg" name="type[email]" type="checkbox" id="email_ckeckbox"> E-mails</label></div>   
<div class="col-xs-4"><input class="form-control" name="emquantity" max="999999999" type="number" id="input_field" ></div>        

<script>
$(document).ready(functon(){
    $(".checkbox-inline").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $(this).closest(".form-control").attr("required","required"); // this is only for HTML 5 validation
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).closest(".form-control").removeAttr("required");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This code will work only for HTML5 form submit validation, if you have used another js library then you have to follow their rules.

Comment: Thank you Haresh Vidja my problem is that i had multiple fields not only one and i don't need to write it for each one

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
   var mainobj = $(this).closest(".col-xs-8").closest(".clearfix").find("input");
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      mainobj.attr("required","required"); // add required if checked
   } else {
      mainobj.removeAttr("required"); // remove required if not checked
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><label><input class="checkbox-inline input-lg" name="type[email]" type="checkbox"> E-mails</label></div>   
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input class="form-control" name="emquantity" max="999999999" type="number" ></div>                  
</div>
<div class="clearfix col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><label><input class="checkbox-inline input-lg" name="type[sms]" type="checkbox"> sms</label></div>   
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input class="form-control" name="smsquantity" max="999999999" type="number" ></div>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you want:

1. When input is checked, add require attribute to the closest input number
2. When input in unchecked, remove require attribute and disabled input number

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox-inline').on('change',function(){
     var isChecked = ($(this).is(":checked")) ? true : false;
     if(isChecked)
     {
            //Active input number and add require
            $(this).closest('.clearfix').find('.form-control').prop('disabled', !isChecked).attr("required","required");
     }
     else
     {
            //Disabled input number and remove require
            $(this).closest('.clearfix').find('.form-control').removeAttr("required").prop('disabled', !isChecked);
     }

  });

});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbbb2m98/